# backingStoreRatio - valid or deprecated?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, retina-display, hdpi

This html5rocks.com article on [High DPI Canvas](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/) has been recomended on several places across SO. It describes how to use the backingStoreRatio value to correctly scale bitmaps on high DPI screens (retina etc). But I can not find any further reference to backingStoreRatio attribute in MDNs reference on [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) nor with any other authority on the web.

Is this solution valid or deprecated? What is the recommended solution to drawing bitmaps to canvas on high res displays?